# How to shift the django admin features to front end

Tags: python, django

I am making an application in django and python. But i have only one user and its for my personal use.

So I am confused between front end and backend because all will be doing al CRUD operation on Classes. So for me evryting will be on frontend , no backend.

But all CRUD operations are done in backend. so is there any way tos shift CRUD functionality to fron end , so that i don't have to create forms for CRUD operations

Comment: Why bother? If the admin gives you enough to do the operations you need, so use it. It checks and warns if you delete things that have objects referenced in them, handles passwords and access control. You can even skin the admin and modify the forms if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need some code for the list views, pagination, etc., but most of the CRUD basic logic can be done using [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Example:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

Now this form contains all the fields of your Article model;
If you pass the form a instance you can edit a existing model instance.